# Не открывает файл для чтения - Python

Tags: python

Делаю, как в уроке, но файл не находит. Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка.
Как сделать, чтобы файл открывался по указанному пути?

```
handle = open("M:\zDownloads\numbers.txt", "r")
for line in handle:
    print(line)
handle.close()

handle = open("C:\numbers.txt", "r")
for line in handle:
    print(line)
handle.close()
```

Comment: У вас точно есть в системе диск М?

Comment: Да есть. Даже на диске C не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте везде перед началом пути поставить `r`. `r"M:\zDownloads\numbers.txt"`.

Comment: Да заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: А чем отличается режим "a" от "a+"?

Comment: `a` открывает только на дозапись, `a+` на дозапись и чтение. Хороший ответ на en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036/10941639. [Документация функции open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо перед каждой строкой пути поставить `r` (raw). `r"M:\zDownloads\numbers.txt"`, либо самому экранировать все спец. символы, типа `"\n"`: `"M:\zDownloads\\numbers.txt"`.

---

Строка `"M:\zDownloads\numbers.txt"` воспринимается, как:

```py
"M:\zDownloads" + перенос_строки + "umbers.txt"
```